# Chartjs-plugin: How to add a different color to each label?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I have a piechart made with chartjs. I then added a label on each pie thanks to chart-js plugin. Sometimes, the pie background is a bit light, so my white text is not visible enough. I've made a function that check the contrast and color it to black in such a case.

But when applied to chartjs-plugin's label color property, the function runs only once, and keep the same color for all label. How to apply a different color to each label based on its background?

Here is the code:

```js
 plugins: {
                datalabels: {
                  color: function(ctx: any) {
                    [...Array(ctx.dataset.data.length)].map((_, i) => {
                      return transformColor(ctx.dataset.backgroundColor[i]);
                    });
                  },
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

here is the rendering of my current piechart:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide `backgroundColor: []` in `Pie` Chart for background color. Here is the complete example:

```
import React from "react";
import {makeStyles} from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import {Pie} from "react-chartjs-2";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    chart: {
        marginLeft: theme.spacing(2)
    }
}));

export default function PieChartExample(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [data, setdata] = React.useState({
        labels: ["type1", "type2", "type3", "type4"],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "No. of registrations made",
                backgroundColor: [
                    "#3e95cd",
                    "#8e5ea2",
                    "#3cba9f",
                    "#e8c3b9",
                    "#c45850"
                ],
                barThickness: 80,
                data: [50, 100, 75, 20, 0]
            }
        ]
    });

    const getChartData = canvas => {
        return data;
    };
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div
                className={classes.chart}
                style={{position: "relative", width: 900, height: 450}}
            >
                <Pie
                    options={{
                        responsive: true,
                        maintainAspectRatio: true,
                        legend: {display: true},
                        title: {
                            display: true,
                            text: "Title for the graph"
                        }
                    }}
                    onElementsClick={(e) => { console.log(e, 'e')}}
                    data={getChartData}
                />
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, however I'm afraid it is not exactly what I'm looking for. I'm talking about changing the color of the label inside each pie. Displaying a label inside each pie can only be achieved with chartjs-plugin. I already have a properly formatted dataset.

Comment: I just updated my example when you were writing comment. I am not sure you checked my update or not. can you please check it and let me know?

Comment: I've run your example in a sandbox, it's not what I'm looking for :(. I'm talking about the label inside each pie. I've edited my original post with a picture so my request is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is way too late response but here's what I got.
You need to return the array of the colors as well not a single color string

```
color: function(ctx: { dataset: { backgroundColor: string[] } }) {
          const backgroundColors = ctx.dataset.backgroundColor || [];
          const textColors: string[] = [];
          backgroundColors.forEach(item => {
            if (isString(item)) {
              const [r, g, b] = item
                .split("(")[1]
                .split(")")[0]
                .split(",");

              const luminance =
                0.299 * Number(r) + 0.587 * Number(g) + 0.114 * Number(b);
              textColors.push(luminance > 128 ? "black" : "white");
            }
          });
          return textColors;
        }
```

the reason of the split string method I used is because I used a random color generator that return values in "rgb()" for the backgoundColor for each arc which is as

```
dynamicColors() {
    const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    const g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    const b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    return "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
  }
```

Comment: You can use a RegExp to extract numbers from the rgb string, instead of doing so many split string calls